# Using the Ruby CKAN client?

Tags: ruby, api, opendata, ckan

I've started exploring the [CKAN Ruby client](https://github.com/apohllo/CKAN) and I can't seem to fully grasp it. This is what I came up with:

```
require "ckan"

CKAN::Package.find(:tags => ["statistics"]).each do |pack|
  puts pack
end
# CKAN::Package[2000-us-census-rdf]
# CKAN::Package[adb-sdbs]
# CKAN::Package[at-statistics]
# CKAN::Package[au-abs]
# ...and tons more...
```

This gives me a all packages with the tag `statistics`. Let's say I want the `nhs` package which is displayed as `CKAN::Package[nhs]` in the output generated above. This is the part I'm stuck at. How do I actually use that package? How do I read its data? I guess it will give me JSON? I have had a look at its [source code](https://github.com/apohllo/CKAN/tree/master/lib/ckan) and it seems reasonably easy to understand though I am not sure which class to use.

Answer (score 1):

if you take a look at the [Package Class](https://github.com/apohllo/CKAN/blob/master/lib/ckan/package.rb) you will see the attributes u can access with this library:

`:name, :title, :url, :version, :author, :author_email,
      :maintainer, :maintainer_email, :license_id, :notes`

Did you want the package informations or the resource information?

Comment: Thanks. I wanted anything that gives me JSON so I guess resource information (which will have a link to a JSON file?).

Comment: Otherwise you can write a JSON wrapper for the Action API http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api.html#action-api.
`/api/3/action/package_show?id=`